# Send messages between iOS and WatchOS with WatchConnectivity in watchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, watchos-2

I watched the WWDC2015 and saw that you can develop native apps on the watch now. This opened up a lot of capabilities and I am wondering how I could send data between my iOS app and my AppleWatch app.

I saw that there is a new framework called WatchConnectivity. How can I use this and what are my options when sending data back and forth?

Comment: you have answered your own question. That's a great way to share your knowledge, as said in StackExchange.com FAQs.

Comment: Achievement unlocked!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**WatchConnectivity**

First the two classes that are supposed to communicate with each other (iOS and watchOS) need to conform the `<WCSessionDelegate>` and `#import` the `WatchConnectivity` framework

Before you can send data you need to check if your device is able to send data

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
      WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
      session.delegate = self;
      [session activateSession];
      NSLog(@"WCSession is supported");
}
```

Then if you wish to use "interactive messaging" (sendMessage APIs) you will need to see if the other device is reachable first:

```
if ([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable]) {
    //Here is where you will send you data
}
```

The "background operations" APIs do not require the counterpart device to be reachable at the point in time you call the WCSession API.

You have several options when it comes to transferring data between your apps, in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WCSession) they are described like this:

- Use the `updateApplicationContext:error:` method to communicate only the most recent state information to the counterpart. When the counterpart wakes, it can use this information to update its own state and remain in sync. Sending a new dictionary with this method overwrites the previous dictionary.
- Use the `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` or `sendMessageData:replyHandler:errorHandler:` method to transfer data immediately to the counterpart. These methods are intended for immediate communication when your iOS app and WatchKit extension are both active.
- Use the `transferUserInfo:` method to transfer a dictionary of data in the background. The dictionaries you send are queued for delivery to the counterpart and transfers continue when the current app is suspended or terminated.
- Use the `transferFile:metadata:` method to transfer files in the background. Use this method in cases where you want to send more than a simple dictionary of values. For example, use this method to send images or file-based documents.

I will give you an example how to send/receive data with **Application Context**

Send data:

```
WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
NSError *error;

[session updateApplicationContext:@{@"firstItem": @"item1", @"secondItem":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]} error:&error];
```

Receive data:

```
- (void) session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {

    NSLog(@"%@", applicationContext);


    NSString *item1 = [applicationContext objectForKey:@"firstItem"];
    int item2 = [[applicationContext objectForKey:@"secondItem"] intValue];
}
```

For more information about WatchConnectivity I really recommend watching the [WWDC2015 session video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713) and reading the [Apple Documentation on WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html)

Comment: does the context have to be of property types? I have a core data entity of a custom class that I would like to send over. Seems to throw an error though.

Comment: There is sample code using sendMessage() on github see: https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/sendMessage

Comment: @Philip how do you close the session once the two-way communication is over (e.g. workout completes etc.)?  Don't want to keep burning cycles / battery more than necessary, but I don't see any methods to close or deactivate the WCSession.