# Close/Deactivate WCSession

Tags: ios, session, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am developing an iPhone app (iOS 9 beta) with watch extension (watchOS 2), and to pass the data from watch to phone I am using WCSession.

I have 2 different view controllers using WCSessions, so for each of the controller I am instantiating new WCSession object. For the first view controller it works fine, but when I want to receive messages in second view controller, few initial messages are still being sent to first controller.

Is there any way I can deactivate / disable session of first view controller before going to second controller? Or are there any other options I should look into?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of WC messages are you sending? InstantMessage? ApplicationData?

Comment: To people from future: the constructor of `WCSession` is now private as in Watch OS 2 release.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When you are passing data back and forth you are sending Dictionaries. If you specify good keys you could get the appropriate data for each ViewController.

Example:

ViewController1:

```
[session updateApplicationContext:@{@"viewController1": @"item1"} error:&error];
```

ViewController2:

```
[session updateApplicationContext:@{@"viewController2": @"item2"} error:&error];
```

When you are receiving data:

```
- (void) session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {

    if ([applicationContext objectForKey:@"viewController1"]) {
        //ViewController1 data
    } else if ([applicationContext objectForKey:@"viewController2"]) {
        //ViewController2 data
    }
}
```

Look at the answer here to learn more about WC [Send messages between iOS and WatchOS with WatchConnectivity in watchOS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457811/send-messages-between-ios-and-watchos-with-watchconnectivity-in-watchos2)

Comment: I feel like this doesn't answer the question. The question was about how to deactivate the session, not how to pass data

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how to deactivate or close a WCSession.